# Use NInject to provide Rhino Mock objects to WebApi controllers - Stubs allways return null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to unit test my WebApi controllers using an Owin in-memory server which is invoked from my *[ClassInitialize]* (MS Test) method. I need to inject mocked instances of my repository object *IFourSquareRepository* via a DI container into my controllers. The Owin server setup, the static Ninject IKernel instance and it's bindings are handled in the Owin configuration class in the WebApi project when the test class [ClassInitialize] method executes:

```
            kernel.Bind<IFourSquareRepository>().ToMethod( 
            context => 
                {
                    return MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFourSquareRepository>(); 
                    // This block runs only once ...
                    // But stubs from the test method return null when the test call 
                    // fires up the controller ...
                }
                ).InSingletonScope();
```

When evaluated from within the test method in my test project, these stubs work predictably (ie: They return the value that I specify in the stub definition below).

My *[TestMethod]* cases creates stubs for the methods of the mocked interface *(IFourSquareRepository)* on which my controllers depend, and calls the WebApi endpoints that resolve onto my WebApi controllers as shown below - (as I'm sending an HttpClient request I can't manually inject my mock object into a controller instance - I rely on the WebApi pipeline to create the controller instance, so I have to use a DI container to inject a mocked *IFourSquareRepository* object into the controller) :

```
       [TestMethod]
    public void Test1_InMemServer()
    {
        var testRet = new BookmarkedPlace() { Id = 99 };
        string userName = "Joe";
        this.MockRepository.Stub(
            repo => repo.GetFirstBookmarkedPlace()).Return(testRet);
        // stub for test Repo IF method

        // Act User the base class static HttpClient to talk to the Owin-hosted WebApi  
        var response = InMemoryTest.HttpClient.GetAsync( string.Format("/api/places/{0}", userName) ).Result;
        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Request Failed ");


    }
```

My problem is that whatever I do, when the controller (which is invoked from my HttpClient request above) calls the stubbed method, it ALLWAYS returns NULL !!

```
       public IEnumerable<BookmarkedPlace> Get(string userName, int page = 0, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        IQueryable<BookmarkedPlace> query;

        query = this.Repository.GetFirstBookmarkedPlace();
        // Mock Repo call returning null !

        // Other stuff goes here ...

        return results;

    }
```

I've been banging my head on this issue for a couple of days - any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that when you create your mock repository, which I am sure int he backend must use some sort of a context as a dependency to call into would also be stubbed, so wont map to actual dbsets.

In the past I have used the way below to mock my repository and get an instance of the DbSet in my Base Test class (since this is common to generation)

```
public static IDbSet<T> GenerateSet<T>(IList<T> data) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        IDbSet<T> dbSet = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<T>, IQueryable>();
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.Provider).Return(queryable.Provider);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.Expression).Return(queryable.Expression);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.ElementType).Return(queryable.ElementType);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(x => queryable.GetEnumerator());

        return dbSet;
    }
```

And then in the Test class in the Initialise I do:

```
[TestInitialize]
    public new void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        _context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<YourContextInterface>();
        _context.Stub(x => x.YourDbSet).PropertyBehavior();
        _context.YourDbSet= GenerateSet(YourDbSet);
    }
```